# How to efficiently design components / configure store when using react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

If I have a component tree such that,

```
//App.js
const App = () => (
      <React.Fragment>
        <A />
        <B />
        <C />
      </React.Fragment>
    )

//A.js
const A = () => (
      <React.Fragment>
        <ChildA />
      </React.Fragment>
)
```

Now, lets say all three components `A`, `B`, `C` are connected to store using `connect()`. 
The problem is if I update the store with data only relevant to component `A`, then `B`, `C` will also be re-rendered. One of the possible solution would be to configure the `options` parameter to avoid re-renders as mentioned in [docs](https://react-redux.js.org/5.x/api/connect#arguments).

Does creating multiple reducer functions for each mutually exclusive components solve this problem ? If yes, how and if No, then what could be done to minimise unnecessary re-rendering.

**UPDATE:** 
In addition to @tmdesigned's answer, if I create a child component of `A`, then some update in `childA` causes both `A` and `childA` to re-render, with `childA` re-rendering twice since both are connected to common reducer function.

See, @tmdesigned's sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-wildflower-3cevg),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was interested in your question, and checked back a few times hoping someone would answer and I could get a deeper understanding of how this works. But that didn't happen, so I did some investigation and set up a code sandbox to illustrate exactly what you asked.

https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-thunder-xbj5z

There you will find a simple React + Redux application with 3 components (A,B, and C) each relying on a different reducer (reducerA, reducerB, and reducerC) and able to trigger an action that updates their reducer (actionA, actionB, and actionC).

You'll see a `console.log` statement in each component's render method, making it clear when each component is re-rendered.

Play around a bit, and you'll discover that the components are *already* intelligently re-rendering only when the redux state they care about is updated--not whenever any part of the store is updated.

In other words, it actually doesn't work like what you suggested ("if I update the store with data only relevant to component A, then B, C will also be re-rendered."). Of course, there are a lot of ways that these other components could re-render, but in the most basic example here, they don't.

Cool, huh?

Comment: I believe we need to be very careful in connecting components to the redux store, at least we should only connect top level components to store only, and pass down data to their child components as props. This will limit at least the extra rendering of the child component.

Comment: That's an interesting question. One of the big benefits of redux is that you can access the store anywhere and don't need to do property chaining like what you're talking about. However you're at least partially right. I've updated the example with a child component. Interestingly you do get a double re-render when the child triggers the update, but not when tthe parent triggers it. I'm not sure what is causing the first re-render here, but it's not the redux store updatting anyways (the value is still the earlier value).

Comment: whenever update is triggered by the child component of A, then reducerA updates the states, resulting in re-render of `A`, which also includes re-rendering of children of A too, also since child is also connected to store, an additional re-render happens. Although, it raises more questions but this seems to be a possible reason.

Comment: But with that, why wouldnt hitting the button on A cause those same 2 re-renders? One for redux->child update, one for redux->parent update->child update?

Comment: Actually, it wasn't re-rendering because of the store update after all, like I suggested a couple of comments ago. It was a leftover setState call that wasn't necessary anymore, causing the sub component to rerender an extra time (thanks to my colleague for pointing this out.)

Comment: looks like react-redux had already implemented a lot of optimizations so that we can use it in a very abstract manner. Thanks for the sandbox link, :)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion each component needs to have it own functionality, it's important this to prevent cases like you said. For example component A renders a list of persons it needs to have its own reducer and actions. For example:

persons state

```
persons: {
  data: [...]
  loading: false
  error: null
}
```

persons actions
`PERSONS_FETCH_INIT` `PERSONS_FETCH_SUCCESS` `PERSONS_FETCH_FAIL`

Also you will need to use react memo, if the state that the component A is subscribed updates component A will trigger a re-render to the component App and then all the children components like B, C, etc will re-render.

Comment: You seem to suggest to create a reducer for each major component in the application. But still I am not convinced with this idea of creating just three actions for each reducer function.

Comment: Not exactly, a action and a reducer for each state of the store like: users, auth, etc. If you give me an overview of your app i can help you out model the store! :)